# Bulk import in custom taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, import

I have a large csv file that contains a photo url and a title. I have created a custom taxonomy of my custom post type. I've made a photo field of this taxonomy with ACF and I'm looking for an option to bulk upload everything.  I tried with WP All Import Pro plugin, but there is no option to set a taxonomy photo on this ACF field and I'm looking for a custom solution.

Comment: Hi @bultim Are you looking for a way to convert .csv data into term meta key/value pairs? For example, if the taxonomy were called **photo**, and the first row of the .csv had **title=garden** and **url=https://bit.ly/?garden_photo**, then would you want a taxonomy term created called **garden**, and term meta key/value pairs created for *title* (key) / *garden* (value), and *url* (key) / *https://bit.ly?garden_photo* (value) for this **garden** taxonomy term? If not, could you please demonstrate how your .csv would be converted into WordPress objects?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: Do you already know how to manage file uploads with PHP? Or would you be placing the .csv file on the server, and using a hard-coded file path to find the file?

Comment: CSV file is on the server and i hard-coded his path.

Answer (score 0):

The **Function: Add new terms and term meta values from .csv file** below should help.

### 1. Requirements

The .csv file must have a header row.

The function below is defined to receive a .csv with a minimum of three columns to fill these [WP_Term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) fields:

1. name,
2. slug, and
3. description.

However, the **suggested function updates** and **variable configurations** below should accommodate a two-column .csv.

### 2. Suggested function updates

Since your .csv file might only have two columns (`title`, `url`), you could change these lines from:

```
'description' => \__( $taxonomy_term[ $taxonomy_term_description ], 'translation_domain' ),
'slug'        => $taxonomy_term[ $slug ],
```

...to...

```
'description' => '',
'slug'        => $taxonomy_term[ $taxonomy_term_name ],
```

...which reuses the `$taxonomy_term_name` column for the slug value.

You could use a function like [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace invalid slug characters. But, nothing needs to be done if you are ok with how WordPress sanitizes the term slug.

### 3. Variable configurations

Update the variables in the function for your .csv by using:

```
// Custom taxonomy name.
$custom_taxonomy = 'TYPE YOUR CUSTOM TAXONOMY NAME HERE';

// .csv column header for the term_name.
$taxonomy_term_name = 'title';

// .csv column header for the term_description.
$taxonomy_term_description = 'title';

// .csv column header for the slug.
$slug = 'title';

// Provide the absolute file path to your .csv on this line in the function below.
$file_path = __DIR__ . '/file.csv';
```

The `url` column will be added to the Term Meta.

## Function: Add new terms and term meta values from .csv file

```
/**
 * Add new terms and term meta values from .csv file.
 *
 * The .csv file must contain column headers for the
 * term_name, term_description, and slug.
 *
 * Update the $custom_taxonomy, $taxonomy_term_name,
 * $taxonomy_term_description and $slug variables
 * with the appropriate values.
 *
 * @param string $file_path
 *
 * @return void
 */
function create_taxonomy_terms( $file_path = '' ) {
    // Custom taxonomy name.
    $custom_taxonomy = 'CUSTOM_TAXONOMY';

    // .csv column header for the term_name.
    $taxonomy_term_name = 'taxonomy_term_name';

    // .csv column header for the term_description.
    $taxonomy_term_description = 'taxonomy_term_description';

    // .csv column header for the slug.
    $slug = 'slug';

    // .csv column header for a column that contains newline characters.
    // This column will be stored in term meta.
    $column_with_newlines = 'csv_header_for_column_containing_newline_characters';

    // For hard-coded file paths.
    if ( empty( $file_path ) ) {
          $file_path = __DIR__ . '/file.csv';
    }

    try {
        $rows = array_map( 'str_getcsv', file( $file_path ) );

        $headers = array_shift( $rows );

        $taxonomy_terms = array();
        foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
            $assoc_array = array();
            foreach ( $headers as $index => $header ) {
                $assoc_array = array_merge( $assoc_array, array( $header => $row[ $index ] ) );
            }

            $taxonomy_terms[] = $assoc_array;
        }

        foreach ( $taxonomy_terms as $taxonomy_term ) {
            $taxonomy_term_exists = \term_exists( $taxonomy_term[ $slug ], $custom_taxonomy );
            if ( $taxonomy_term_exists ) {
                continue;
            }

            $term_ids = \wp_insert_term(
                \__( $taxonomy_term[ $taxonomy_term_name ], 'translation_domain' ),
                $custom_taxonomy,
                array(
                    'description' => \__( $taxonomy_term[ $taxonomy_term_description ], 'translation_domain' ),
                    'slug'        => $taxonomy_term[ $slug ],
                    'parent'      => 0
                )
            );

            // Add taxonomy_term meta data if the .csv spreadsheet columns contain
            // additional data.
            // Term meta will be created for all .csv column headers. To avoid duplication
            // of the taxonomy_term_name, taxonomy_term_description, and slug columns,
            // use IF-Statement conditions to skip creating term meta keys for those columns.
            foreach ( $taxonomy_term as $meta_key => $meta_value ) {
                if ( $column_with_newlines == $meta_key ) {
                    $value  = addcslashes( $meta_value, "\n" );

                    // Can save the $value as a single element array
                    // serialized as a JSON-encoded string.
                    // When using get_term_meta, the value must be
                    // JSON-decoded, and the desired data extracted as the
                    // first eleemnt of an array.
                    // For example:
                    // $json_encoded = \get_term_meta( $term_id, $column_with_newlines, $single_value = true );
                    // $json_decoded = json_decode( $json_encoded, $create_assoc_array = true );
                    // $value        = $json_decoded[0];
                    $meta_value = json_encode(
                        array( $value ),
                        ( JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_QUOT )
                    );
                }

                // Fourth term "$unique": When true add_term_meta is blocked if key already exists.
                $result = \add_term_meta( $term_ids['term_id'], $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique = true );
                if ( \is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
                    die( 'Import error' );
                    // TODO: taxonomy_terms import add_term_meta WP_Error handling.
                }
            }
        }
    } catch ( \Exception $e ) {
        // TODO: Exception handling if taxonomy_terms import used.
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm .. it doesn't work :(

Comment: What is the result? Can you post any error messages?

Comment: Тhat's it. No mistake. White screen and database not filling.

Comment: I followed the instructions as written, and just tested it locally with a two-column .csv file with headers **title** and **url**. It works and correctly populates my wp_term and wp_termmeta tables. One thing I did not include in the instructions is how to call the function. How are you calling the function?

Comment: I calling function with add_action( 'init', 'create_taxonomy_terms' );

Comment: Hi @bultim. Since I do not use ACF, I can only understand if you express your request using WordPress objects (e.g. WP_Post, WP_Term, wp_terms table, wp_term_taxonomy table, etc.), not ACF fields. I do not know how ACF stores its fields (as Term Meta?, as Post Meta?, as wp_options?, etc.). Would you be able to explain how ACF stores its fields? When you say: *I create with ACF field in this taxomony named note_image* I do not know where or how *note_image* is stored. I need to know what your .csv should look like when converted into WordPress objects.

Comment: Yes, good idea to provide a link somewhere that I can download a sample of your .csv file. I would also like to know in what database tables you would like these .csv values to be stored, and how these values should be associated with other values in the same or other database tables. For example, which values should be WP_Terms and which values should be Term meta_keys, and which values should be Term meta_values, and which values should be stored somewhere else (e.g. Post meta_keys or Post meta_values or Custom Post Type meta_keys or Custom Post Type meta_values, etc.). Thanks.

Comment: Would you give me some of your contacts, email or skype or something?

Comment: Hi. If you use GitHub, you can send me a message (open an issue or something). I use the same user name as here.

Answer (score 0):

Оk, i have progress now .. I see the errors.

Warning: Undefined array key "slug" in /autoinstalator/wordpress3/fragransa/wp-content/themes/Fragransa/functions.php on line 585

Warning: Undefined array key "taxonomy_term_name" in /autoinstalator/wordpress3/fragransa/wp-content/themes/Fragransa/functions.php on line 591

Warning: Undefined array key "taxonomy_term_description" in /autoinstalator/wordpress3/fragransa/wp-content/themes/Fragransa/functions.php on line 594

Warning: Undefined array key "slug" in /autoinstalator/wordpress3/fragransa/wp-content/themes/Fragransa/functions.php on line 595

Deprecated: trim(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in /autoinstalator/wordpress3/fragransa/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 2359

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in /autoinstalator/wordpress3/fragransa/wp-content/themes/Fragransa/functions.php:625 Stack trace: #0 /autoinstalator/wordpress3/fragransa/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): create_taxonomy_terms() #1 /autoinstalator/wordpress3/fragransa/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters() #2 /autoinstalator/wordpress3/fragransa/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action() #3 /autoinstalator/wordpress3/fragransa/wp-settings.php(623): do_action() #4 /autoinstalator/wordpress3/fragransa/wp-config.php(96): require_once('...') #5 /autoinstalator/wordpress3/fragransa/wp-load.php(50): require_once('...') #6 /autoinstalator/wordpress3/fragransa/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('...') #7 /autoinstalator/wordpress3/fragransa/index.php(17): require('...') #8 {main} thrown in /autoinstalator/wordpress3/fragransa/wp-content/themes/Fragransa/functions.php on line 625